# how to increase presto query speed by resource usage increase

Tags: presto

I have a presto query doing a group by over a parquet file that is partitioned by id, year, month.
The query takes 15 seconds over 1.3 m records I have lots of cluster resources and would like to speed it up.

Comment: Is it a single Parquet file? Did you try setting e.g. `hive.max-initial-splits=1MB`? (a value that i would not recommend in general, but may improve your case)

Comment: it is a union of 3 files. No i didn't.